# Div's moving out of alignment when HREF added

Tags: html, css, href

I have a row of three images that should be centre aligned and therefore line up with the corresponding divs's below. Each image is in its own Div. They were aligning perfectly, however, when I add an HREF to them, they all just move to the left and I don't understand why. Could someone shed some light on how to fix this?

The JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DcoltGaming/ap2jd1xh/7/

The HTML:

```
<div class="contactUsContainer">
            <a href="">
    <div class="ContactUsBox"> 
         <img src="https://img.icons8.com/plasticine/48/000000/phone.png">
    </div>
            </a>


    <a href="">
    <div class="emailIconBox">
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/nolan/48/email.png">
          </div> 
          </a>


                 <a href="">
              <div class="IMBox"> 
         <img src="https://img.icons8.com/android/48/000000/computer.png">
    </div>  
  </a>


          </div>   

        <div class="contactUsMethodInfoContainer">
              <div class="phoneInfo">
                  <p>Some info about a phone.</p>
              </div>

              <div class="IMInfo">
                  <p>Some info about Social media</p>
              </div>

              <div class="emailInfo">
                  <p>Some info about emails.</p>
              </div>
          </div>
```

The CSS

```
 .contactUsContainer{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.ContactUsBox{
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}


.emailIconBox{
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

.IMBox {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

.contactUsMethodInfoContainer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.phoneInfo{
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1.5%;
}

.IMInfo{
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1.5%;
}

.emailInfo{
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1.5%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `display: flex`, may I suggest you ditch the `width`s all together and instead rely on flexbox properties to handle your layout?

It's as simple as adding `justify-content: space-around;` to get your desired effect:

https://jsfiddle.net/cu5k70e4/

CSS (widths removed on children, `justify-content` applied at parents):

```
.contactUsContainer{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    height: 100%;
}

.ContactUsBox{
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}


.emailIconBox{
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

.IMBox {
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

.contactUsMethodInfoContainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.phoneInfo{
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1.5%;
}

.IMInfo{
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1.5%;
}

.emailInfo{
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1.5%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the  tags the CSS that you are giving your ...Box elements.

```
.contactUsContainer > a {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Or give all your  tags a class and set the styles that way

```
<a class="linkBox" />
.linkBox {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GiorgiosJames/m2dy9Lbe/)

Answer (score 1):

Your contactUsContainer is set to flex, and flex always acts on its immediate children. Before the a tags, the children were ContactUsBox, emailIconBox and IMBox. Once you added the a tags, then the a tags became the immediate children. To solve this, you need to add your desired properties to the a tags:

```css
.contactUsContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

a {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.contactUsMethodInfoContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.phoneInfo {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1.5%;
}

.IMInfo {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1.5%;
}

.emailInfo {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="contactUsContainer">
  <a href="">
    <div class="ContactUsBox">
      <img src="https://img.icons8.com/plasticine/48/000000/phone.png">
    </div>
  </a>


  <a href="">
    <div class="emailIconBox">
      <img src="https://img.icons8.com/nolan/48/email.png">
    </div>
  </a>


  <a href="">
    <div class="IMBox">
      <img src="https://img.icons8.com/android/48/000000/computer.png">
    </div>
  </a>


</div>

<div class="contactUsMethodInfoContainer">
  <div class="phoneInfo">
    <p>Some info about a phone.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="IMInfo">
    <p>Some info about Social media</p>
  </div>

  <div class="emailInfo">
    <p>Some info about emails.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```